# How to mount entire directory in Kubernetes using configmap?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I want to be able to mount an unknown number of config files in /etc/configs

I have added some files to the configmap using:

> kubectl create configmap etc-configs --from-file=/tmp/etc-config

The number of files and file names are never going to be known and I would like to recreate the configmap and the folder in the Kubernetes container should be updated after sync interval.

I have tried to mount this but I'm not able to do so, the folder is always empty but I have data in the configmap.

```
bofh$ kubectl describe configmap etc-configs
Name:         etc-configs
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
file1.conf:
----
{
 ... trunkated ...
}
file2.conf:
----
{
 ... trunkated ...
}
file3.conf:
----
{
 ... trunkated ...
}

Events:  <none>
```

I'm using this one in the container volumeMounts:

```
- name: etc-configs
  mountPath: /etc/configs
```

And this is the volumes:

```
- name: etc-configs
  configMap:
    name: etc-configs
```

I can mount individual items but not an entire directory.

Any suggestions about how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your config, you're going to mount each file listed in your configmap.

If you need to mount all file in a folder, you shouldn't use configmap, but a persistenceVolume and persistenceVolumeClaims:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-volume-jenkins
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 50Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/data/pv-jenkins"
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pv-claim-jenkins
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi
```

---

In your deployment.yml:

```
 volumeMounts:
        - name: jenkins-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /data

  volumes:
        - name: jenkins-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pv-claim-jenkins
```

You can also use the following:

```
kubectl create configmap my-config --from-file=/etc/configs
```

to create the config map with all files in that folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, but I want to mount every single file from the configMap since we are populating the configMap from 3rd party system.

Comment: Do you mean that inside the configMan you wanna list N files and a folder, and you expect that it mounts the folder as is?

Comment: Yes! I don't need folders, I'm happy with a flat structure  with files direct under /etc/configs

Comment: Thanks but that part works. The configmap contains all data but the folder is always empty when I start the POD.

It seems my config is correct but it still don't work. No error messages, the POD starts but /etc/configs is empty

Comment: Using mountPath: /etc/configs, your docker image must have /etc/config inside.
I tried all steps from generating the configMap with the content of a folder until deploying the image and inspecting it. Everything works good.

Comment: Thank you @Nicola for all your help. I have posted my "solution". Kubernetes was working all the time but my container was failing and my troubleshooting method was incorrect. I will up-vote your answer since it you was trying really hard to help me.

Comment: @NicolaBenaglia in your example what is the PersistentVolume used for ?

Comment: @przemolb PV is used to contain and persist all Jenkins data.

Comment: How don't use `hostPath` of the node? I want to upload the files from the dir with conf files in the Project Kubernetes repo.

Answer (score 18):

You can mount the ConfigMap as a special volume into your container.

In this case, the mount folder will show each of the keys as a file in the mount folder and the files will have the map values as content.

From the [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#populate-a-volume-with-data-stored-in-a-configmap):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
...
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /etc/config
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        # Provide the name of the ConfigMap containing the files you want
        # to add to the container
        name: special-config
```

Comment: this seems to be a valid answer for this question

Answer (score 5):

I'm feeling really stupid now.

Sorry, My fault.

The Docker container did not start so I was manually staring it using docker run -it --entrypoint='/bin/bash'  and I could not see any files from the configMap.

This does not work since docker don't know anything about my deployment until Kubernetes starts it.

The docker image was failing and the Kubernetes config was correct all the time.

I was debugging it wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused by the accepted answer and I thought that it's not possible to mount multiple files from a configMap into a directory. In my case, I had to remove subPath.